# Do I have to include the Partition Key in ORDER BY when providing it via QueryRequestOptions (Azure Cosmos DB)

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working with the .NET SDK to perform Cosmos DB queries that involve `ORDER BY` on multiple properties, and I've defined a composite index to optimize these queries. Recently, I made changes to my DAOs by adding `QueryRequestOptions` to specify the partition to be targeted and removing the partition key from the `WHERE` clause.

Here's an example of my code (`CompanyName` is the partition key):

```cs
string query = "SELECT * FROM w 
WHERE w.WorkflowName = @workflowName 
ORDER BY w.CompanyName DESC, w.WorkflowName DESC, w.StartedAt DESC";
var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(query).WithParameter("@workflowName", workflowName);
var options = new QueryRequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(pk) };
var entries = await _container.ExecuteQueryAsync<WorkflowRun>(queryDefinition, options).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

So now I was wondering, since I no longer have to provide the partition key for the `WHERE` clause, do I even have to provide the partition key for the `ORDER BY` clause?

So I ran a quick test (read 1000 entries from a single partition):

- 12,27 RU with a composite index on `CompanyName, WorkflowName, StartedAt`
- 13,48 RU with a composite index on `WorkflowName, StartedAt`

So it seems including it in composite indexes improves (at least) this query.

So my question is, do I always have to provide the partition key for the `ORDER BY` clause (and therefore also add it to the composite index) when performing a query where the partition key is already specified via `QueryRequestOptions`?

I have already worked myself through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy) and the Github issues from the [.NET SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues), but could not find a concrete answer.

Comment: As you are doing an equality on both `CompanyName` and `WorkflowName` - so both of those will only have one distinct value in all returned documents did you also look at RU charge for `ORDER BY w.StartedAt DESC` rather than having a composite order by at all? (not saying it is going to be better but worth also comparing)

Comment: If I remove the composite index and perform `SELECT * FROM c where c.CompanyName = "ASSETCOMPANY" AND c.WorkflowName = "WORKFLOWRENE" ORDER BY c.StartedAt DESC` it results in an RU cost of 22,72.

Answer (score 0):

> do I always have to provide the partition key for the `ORDER BY` clause (and therefore also add it to the composite index) when performing a query where the partition key is already specified via `QueryRequestOptions`?

When executing a query where the partition key is already supplied via `QueryRequestOptions`, you usually do not need to add it to the composite index or provide the partition key for the `ORDER BY` clause.

**Below are the steps I followed:**

- A `CosmosClient` instance is created using the provided **cosmosEndpointUri** and **cosmosPrimaryKey**.
- Build a SQL query that retrieves all documents from the container whose **customerId** matches the provided value.
- The `ORDER BY` clause is used to sort the results by **orderDate** in descending order.
- Specify the `PartitionKey` in `QueryRequestOptions` In order to ensure effective querying within the chosen partition, this instructs Cosmos DB which partition to target for the query.
- `container.GetItemQueryIterator`  creates an iterator to obtain the outcomes in batches.
- Using a `ReadNextAsync` loop through the query results, add the retrieved orders to a list.
- The orders that match the given **customerId** are included in this list, which is arranged in decreasing order by **id**.

**RU's Consumption:**

- 2.83 RU with a composite index on **id**.
- 2.82 RU with a composite index on **customerId**.
- Using a composite index on the `partition key` can help minimize cross-partition queries.
- It makes that your query runs quickly within a single partition, preventing the need to visit additional partitions, which might be more resource-intensive.
- For further on composite index refer this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/three-ways-to-leverage-composite-indexes-in-azure-cosmos-db/#:%7E:text=After%20adding%20a%20composite%20index%2C%20the%20query%E2%80%99s%20RU,the%20ORDER%20BY%20clause%20have%20a%20high%20cardinality.).

**Below Is the code I tried with:**

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(cosmosEndpointUri, cosmosPrimaryKey);
        var database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(databaseId);
        var container = database.GetContainer(containerId);

        string customerId = "12345"; 
        string query = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.customerId = @customerId ORDER BY c.id DESC";
        
        var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(query).WithParameter("@customerId", customerId);
        var requestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(customerId) };
        var queryIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Order>(queryDefinition, requestOptions: requestOptions);
        var orders = new List<Order>();

        while (queryIterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var response = await queryIterator.ReadNextAsync();
            orders.AddRange(response.Resource);
        }

        foreach (var order in orders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Order ID: {order.Id}, Customer ID: {order.CustomerId}, Order Date: {order.OrderDate}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Order ID: 1, Customer ID: 12345, Order Date: 9/15/2023 2:30:00 PM
```

Comment: Hey - Please stop posting ChatGPT-generated content, which is [banned here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1). Half of your answer is just “stating the obvious” like a tutorial, and with things the OP has already clearly done.